# False proof that uniform convergence of Fourier series implies smoothness

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laurent-series

I found the following (obviously mistaken) proof that any continuous function $f\in C[\mathbb{T}]$ for which $|{f-\mathcal{S}_{N}f}|_{\infty}\to0$ must be smooth.

Can you please help me find the flaw?

***The 'proof':***

Suppose that $|{f-\mathcal{S}_{N}f}|_{\infty}\to0$, i.e., the Laurent series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}$ converges on $\partial\mathbb{D}$. In particular: $f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)\left(e^{2\pi it}\right)^{n}$ on $\mathbb{T}$. As a Laurent series must either converge locally uniformly on an open set or diverge everywhere, there is an open neighborhood $\partial\mathbb{D}\subseteq U$ on which the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}$ converges locally uniformly, say to a function $F:U\to\mathbb{C}$.

Now take a point $w\in U\backslash\left\{ 0\right\}$ . As $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}$ converges locally uniformly on U, there is $0<\epsilon<\left|w\right|$ for which the series converges uniformly on $B_{\epsilon}(w)$. Let $\gamma$ be any closed piecewise $C^{1}$ loop in $B_{\epsilon}(w)$. As $\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}$ is analytic on $B_{\epsilon}(w)$ (because it's only pole, $0$, is outside of $B_{\epsilon}(w)$), By Cauchy's Theorem $\int_{\gamma}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}\text{ d}z=0$ for every $N\in\mathbb{N}$. As the convergance on $B_{\epsilon}(w)\subseteq U$ is uniform, by the theorem about swapping a limit with an integral we get:$$\int_{\gamma}F(z)\text{ d}z=\int_{\gamma}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}\text{ d}z=\int_{\gamma}\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}(z)\text{ d}z=$$ $$=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{\gamma}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}\hat{f}(n)z^{n}(z)\text{ d}z=\lim_{N\to\infty}0=0$$The choice of $\gamma$ was arbitrary, hence by Morera's theorem $F$ is analytic on $B_{\epsilon}(w)$, and in particular on $w$. The choice $w$ was arbitrary as well, hence **$F$ is analytic on $U\backslash\left\{ 0\right\}$  which is an open    neighborhood of $\partial\mathbb{D}$**. As mentioned before, for every $t\in\mathbb{T}$ we have: $$f(t)=\mathcal{S} f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)e^{2\pi int}=F\left(e^{2\pi it}\right)$$ Thus $f$ is smooth.

Comment: "As a Laurent series must either converge locally uniformly on an open set or diverge everywhere" is incorrect as for example $\sum_{n \ge 1} z^n/n^2 +\sum_{n \ge 1} z^{-n}/n^2$ converges only on the unit circle and nowhere else, so in particular not on any open set containing it

Comment: for any Fourier series (trigonometric series coming from an integrable function), the "analytic" part ($\sum a_ne^{int}, n \ge 0$) converges on the unit disc and the anti-analytic part converges on the exterior of the unit disc, but you need very fast convergence (to zero) of the respective coefficients for the convergence of either subseries beyond their domains above

Comment: @Conrad Yes you are completely correct. Thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: @Conrad Is it still true though that the Laurent series converges locally uniformly wherever it converges?

Comment: a Laurent series has two parts, an analytic part, and an inverse analytic part so it's useful to look at them separately; the first converges on a disc as usual and the second converges on a disc exterior as usual; if those intersect in a non empty annulus the convergence there is as usual (locally uniform etc); however it may happen that they only touch on the common boundary circle and there the convergence depends on the specific coefficients - Fourier series are special cases of this phenomenon where the corresponding "Laurent" series generally converges only on the circle (if at all)

Comment: So it depends in a sense on what you allow to be called a Laurent series - usually, the common annulus is implied, but one can consider formal Laurent series where the two regions of convergence may be disjoint (one or both of the subseries may even not converge except at $0$ or $\infty$ respectively) or the two regions just have the boundary in common- this last is the theory of trigonometric series which is interesting and difficult even in its simpler Fourier series subpart -

Comment: for example, there are trigonometric series that converge everywhere but are not Fourier series ( eg $\sum_{n \ge 2} \sin nx /\log n$ - this corresponds to the "Laurent" series $\sum z^n/(2i \log n)-\sum z^{-n}/(2i \log n)$) but if a trigonometric series converges everywhere to an integrable function then it must be the Fourier series of that function and this last is a non trivial and difficult theorem to prove (even when the function in cause is $0$)